# How to capture error in SQL Server stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, error-handling

I need to capture the error and send it to the web application. For example, the below is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROC ADDNAME
   (@FirstName VARCHAR(10),
    @LastName VARCHAR(10))
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN
       INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(FirstName, LastName) 
       VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName)
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
       ROLLBACK TRAN
       PRINT @@ERRORMESSAGE
    END CATCH
END
```

Here, how to capture the error and send it to the web application? Normally, which is the best method to handle stored procedure errors from web application?

I am using ASP.NET & C# as a front end. I need your suggestions.

Comment: you can use RAISERROR(Transact-SQL) try this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx

Comment: Yes. In catch block, I generate the error by the things specified in the above link. But how do we send the error to the front end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you cannot rollback in BEGIN CATCH. Not without checking [`XACT_STATE()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189797.aspx) first. Unless the `xact_state()` is 1, you cannot run ROLLBACK. Think about the trivial case when the exception is 1205 (a deadlock has occurred) in which case you get the exception *after* your transaction was forcefully rolled back. See [Exception handling and nested transactions](http://rusanu.com/2009/06/11/exception-handling-and-nested-transactions/) for a correct pattern that mixes transactions and error handling.

Second, your stored procedure does not need transaction and error handling *as is*. Unless the real code is much more complex, your procedure doesn't add any value.

Lastly, to raise an error use [`RAISERROR()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx). SQL Server 2012 has also [`THROW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677615.aspx).

Comment: Actually, I just written the stored procedure for example purpose.

Comment: Do we need to send the raiserror as an output parameter to the front end?

Comment: try{ //db connection } catch(Exception e) { // e.message gets the message from raiserror() I think.} in c#

Comment: Errors raised and not caught in T-SQL are sent to client.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this: Code in SQL

```
create procedure sp_err_msg
as begin
    -- RAISERROR with severity 11-19 will cause execution to 
    -- jump to the CATCH block.
    -- better place this inside catch block
    -- RAISERROR ('Error raised in TRY block.', -- Message text.
    --           11, -- Severity.
    --           1 -- State.
    --       );
    raiserror('error message', 11, 1);
end
```

Code in C#. Just to show how to get the error from SQL

```
public static string GetErrorMessage() 
{
  string errMsg = null;
  try
  {
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) 
    {
      using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_err_msg", con)) 
      {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        con.Open();

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
      con.Close();
    } 
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
    errMsg = e.Message;
  }

  return errMsg;
}
```